# How to Query Post

Tags: query-posts

On my homepage I have a slider at the top and then three columns below that. I would like to pull the three latest post for a category in each column. So each column will have three post titles and dates for a single category.

Can anyone tell me what the Query would be?

Thanks in advance,

14ner

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> - <?php the_date(); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

More info:
[query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was wondering if there is a way to use category "name" not id number because for some reason my events category doesn't work.  I was also wonder if there was a way to list these post titles without bullets.  Thanks,  14ner

Comment: @14ner category name can be easily converted to IF with [`get_cat_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID) function.

Comment: To remove bullets, see the "Applying the CSS" section of this page of the WordPress documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Horizontal_Menus